# How to make texture white in the locations that objects hit it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I have a cylinder with various glass objects sticking out of the sides:
[image]

This cylinder has a texture:

[image]

I would like the texture to have white spots in all the places that are intersected by glass objects. How do I do that?

It would be very nice if it could be done with just nodes, but, if not, thats also fine.
[image]

Comment: Could you include a picture with the result you would like to obtain?

Comment: @FacebFaceb  I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing that... without the glass things, it would look kinda like a mushroom from all the white circles in it.

Comment: An option could be the 'dynamic paint' in the physics tab, where the textured mesh is a canvas and each sphere is a brush